# the query running too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

Given is mySQL table named "user_posts" with the following relevant fields:

- user_id
- user_status
- influencer_status

indexed in all three fields

My running slow query is here and also i have created an **[dbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3A8bEEoCD8t41ZAoTsq8Va/0)** . Output of Explain is in the **[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3A8bEEoCD8t41ZAoTsq8Va/0)**:

```
SELECT 
   P.user_post_id,     
   P.user_id_fk,P.post_type,
   P.who_can_see_post,
   P.post_image_id,P.post_video_id, 
   U.user_name, U.user_fullname,U.influencer_status 
 FROM user_posts P FORCE INDEX (ix_user_posts_post_id_post_type)
   INNER JOIN users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status_istatus)
   ON P.user_id_fk = U.user_id 
 WHERE 
   U.user_status='1' AND 
   U.influencer_status = '1' AND 
   (P.who_can_see_post IN('everyone','influencer','friends')) AND 
   (P.post_type IN('image','video'))
   AND p.user_post_id > 30
 ORDER BY 
    P.user_post_id 
 DESC LIMIT 30
```

The query takes extremely long, around 6-15 seconds. The database is not very busy otherwise and performs well on other queries.

I am obviously wondering why the query is so slow.

Is there a way to tell exactly what is taking mySQL so long? Or is there any change I need to make to make the query run faster?

Comment: SQL Fiddle is not working (opening) as usual.. Please setup the two fiddles here: https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks. I have created db-fiddle . Here is the demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3A8bEEoCD8t41ZAoTsq8Va/0

Answer (score 4):

The definition of your `ix_status_istatus` key is preventing it being used to optimise the `WHERE` clause, as it includes `user_id` which is not used in the `WHERE` clause. Redefining the index as

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY ix_status_istatus (user_status, influencer_status);
```

allows it to be used and should speed up your query, changing the search on `users` to use `index` instead of `temporary and filesort`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rK9kHjLXw9bspaqox88N7e/0)

**Update**

Further analysis on dbfiddle suggests that it is also better to remove the `FORCE INDEX` from the `P` table as it is not necessary (only the `PRIMARY` key is required) and changing the `JOIN` to a [`STRAIGHT_JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) i.e. write the `JOIN` as:

```
FROM user_posts P 
STRAIGHT_JOIN users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status_istatus)
ON P.user_id_fk = U.user_id
```

Comment: How do I change the key I defined earlier?

Comment: Nick: explanation does not connect with what actually changed in the query execution plan; it is actually a side-effect of the change in users index; but the problem is actually in the index in Posts table. @DeltaForce you basically need to change the index in the `Posts` table instead:  `ALTER TABLE user_posts DROP INDEX ix_user_posts_post_id_post_type; ALTER TABLE user_posts ADD KEY ix_user_posts_post_id_post_type (user_post_id);` . Check this fiddle for the query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3A8bEEoCD8t41ZAoTsq8Va/3

Comment: Moreover, if we read [Nested Loop Join algorithm](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html), `user_id` is a JOIN condition, and it is required in the index. It is working for your modified indexes because InnoDB clusters secondary indexes with the Primary Key (which happens to be user_id in this case).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It takes `9 second` right now. I have `2162 user` and `875 total post`. `675 image` post `57 video` post. All `user status` is `1` and `influencer status` `1` users are `98`.

Comment: @DeltaForce what is taking 9 seconds ? which query and what indexes are you using now ? Do the following: `EXPLAIN format=JSON SELECT ..(your query)` and post the resultant JSON to the question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I mean, The opening speed of the page takes 9 seconds. I am using your query and Nicks' answer indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199832/discussion-between-deltaforce-and-madhur-bhaiya).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Here is the Explain : `object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } `

Comment: @DeltaForce pls check the discussions happening here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199832/discussion-between-deltaforce-and-madhur-bhaiya

Answer (score 0):

I think You should limit result set of joining part using conditions inside ON statement.

It’s like doing filtering during joining instead of joining then filtering.

I’ve checked query plan which shows me full utilization of indexes.

```
SELECT 
   P.user_post_id,     
   P.user_id_fk,P.post_type,
   P.who_can_see_post,
   P.post_image_id,
   P.post_video_id, 
   U.user_name, 
   U.user_fullname,
   U.influencer_status 

 FROM user_posts P

 INNER JOIN 
   users U 
       FORCE INDEX (
         users_user_status_index, 
         users_influencer_status_index
       )
   ON 
     U.user_id = P.user_id_fk AND 
     U.user_status='1' AND 
     U.influencer_status='1'

 WHERE 
   P.who_can_see_post IN('everyone','influencer','friends') AND 
   P.post_type IN('image','video') AND 
   P.user_post_id > 30

 ORDER BY 
    P.user_post_id DESC

 LIMIT 30
```

Indexes that I created:

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY users_user_status_index(user_status),
  ADD KEY users_influencer_status_index(influencer_status);
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6GuyEo2hnHug6HY3iG9TnP/2)

Comment: I have tryed your answer the query running in 11-18 second.

Comment: @DeltaForce try my updated answer, create 2 separate indexes that I've added in my answer